# How to select a frame using selenium with target?

Tags: python, selenium

```
link = driver.find_element_by_partial_link_text('/wse/gupmenug.menu?p_sistema_c=ESCOLAR&amp;p_sistemaid_n=1&amp;p_menupredid_n=1&amp;p_pidm_n=425370')
```

How can i fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your locator indeed looks invalid.
using the expected conditions and better locators it will be something like this:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)

wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//a[text()='ALUMNOS']"))).click()

wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//a[text()='ESCOLAR']"))).click()
```

Comment: I hope this will work. In case it will not - will need more details, preferably to see your web page link.